# Osgi event hook find hook - proxy

Tags: java, proxy, osgi, hook

I am trying to implement a method level cache in OSGI services using the EventListenerHook and FindHook. The idea is a few services deemed cacheable will be proxied and if the method is deemed cacheable the service is proxied. Any other service that needs a cacheable service will now get an instance of proxy. With in the proxy I do the cache lookup and if not found entry added to cache.

It all works very well for simple services. The problem starts when I have a service with a list of configurable properties (metatype=true) managed via ConfigAdmin.

What exactly happens when I update a property in Configuration Admin in Felix console? A new service is registered in Service Registry? I was under the impression, no service event is triggered. Only the activate/modified/deactivate method in the service is invoked. Is my understanding incorrect?

Thanks
Jai